# Background pattern effects in relation to Mobile devices

Tags: css, graphics, background-image

I was wondering this last night and couldn't find a direct answer so I shall ask here.  In extreme backgrounds that you are not wanting a constant but yet subtle effect to be visible.  How do you accommodate this for mobile design and what happens to the background if the pattern is larger than the screen size?  I ask this for certain reasons because I don't know what would happen to the background.  Would it not display, shrink, or repeat?  Would you code in the a special background for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your CSS....

Since you can set no-repeat, center, cover and various of other options in the CSS. So if you use width:100%, height:100% then it'll shrink or you could use cover which will do the same. If you want a pattern repeating then you use repeat etc etc. You can even specify a different liter background for mobile phones and pads such as:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:767px){
html, body {background-image:url("image.jpg");}
}
```

Your find that with iPhones and iPads they upscale and then downscale and images can look horrid but there's ways around this using the css cover element.